# Checking user input in Link List (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a link list here to check for user input to see whether user has input the word before or not.

```
ListNode *cur = head;

while ( cur != NULL )
{
    if ( guess == cur->item )
    {
        return true;
    }

    cur = cur->next;
}

return false;
```

My problem is that even though the list is empty, it'll still enter the `while` loop. What's my mistake?

Comment: You just checked that `cur != NULL`, i.e., this test will never be successful and can safely be removed. Why you would get a run-time error at this code, I don't know: what did the error say?

Comment: What is the exact error? Btw the test `cur == NULL` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: The only place I see where an error can occur is with `guess == cur->item` if `cur` doesn't contain a pointer value referencing valid memory. Chances are you are not properly setting `next` to null when you add a node to the end of the list.

Comment: When you added a node in your list did you make its `->next` `NULL`? Because if not, then `next` contains junk and it's not `NULL` either

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for pointing it out to me. I didn't get error just program crashes.

Comment: @IosifM. No, I didn't set to NULL.

My question now is how do I check for the first node? If it's NULL.

Comment: you mean, how do you check for `head == NULL`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Well, I haven't went through there yet. Now my problem stuck at the first node when the list is NULL contains no data.

Comment: @IosifM. Yes. How can I check if my list is empty? I know it's a stupid question.

Comment: if `head` is `NULL` your list is empty... (or corrupted and unusable)

Comment: At first run, my program list is empty. When I wanted to check, for empty list, the program gives me error. How do I avoid the program to return true when the list is empty? I've tried 

     head == NULL

and still the program gives me error

Comment: well if your list is empty, then don't return `true`. `if (!head) return false;`

Comment: I've realize that altough my list is empty, it won't go to `if (!head) return false;` instead it jump to the while loop. I've edit my code on my question.

Comment: If it enters the `while` loop then `head` isn't null.

Comment: @interjay the list is empty and head isn't null? I too think the head isn't null but it's an empty list. Must've been something in my code. Will look at it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you initialize the empty list with `head=NULL;`? Otherwise `head` will most likely point to some random memory, and it will be impossible to detect that the list is empty.